# Display absolute div above another absolute div

Tags: html, css

My use case is the following:

I have an application (let's say a chat application) with several messages. The `HTML` would be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="picture"><img /></div>
        <div class="message">My message</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="picture"><img /></div>
        <div class="message">My second message</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's what I did. But in my application I need to be able to click on a picture to display a menu beside it.
That's ok for this point.

But where I'm having trouble is when I try to display an overlay between the chat and the menu.

I tried this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="picture">
            <img />
            <div class="menu">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="message">My message</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="picture"><img /></div>
        <div class="message">My second message</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="backdrop"></div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.picture {
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

.backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

But this is not working, my menu is displayed under the overlay.

Also, I can't put the menu inside the .backdrop element because each picture can have a different menu with links to diff

**EDIT**

I have more information about my issue.

Actually the `.container` block is `position: absolute;` with `z-index: 3;`

Here is a fiddle demonstrating my issue : https://jsfiddle.net/e9kcaau2/

I also tried with my overlay having a `z-index: 3;` but it's still not working

Comment: Which browser is displaying the menu under the overlay? A quick fiddle shows your menu is on top of the overlay: http://jsfiddle.net/e9kcaau2/ (at least in Chrome - or I'm totally missing your question...)

Comment: I'm testing it with Chrome. This code is only a sample, I'll make a "non-working" fiddle as soon as I have some time to illustrate my issue

Comment: @JackPattishall I edited my question with more information and a fiddle reproducing the issue